# Law of Cosines JAVA

Tags: java, math, methods, trigonometry

I'm trying to create a method for the Law of cosines and failing miserably 
Using

a = 8

b = 9

c = 5

The output should be **0.80693439407**

With this I got **0.8546475409378381** as output

```
public  double cos(double a, double b, double c)
    { 
        double ang=(Math.pow(a,2))-(Math.pow(b,2)-Math.pow(c,2))/(2*b*c);
        return Math.cos(ang);
    }
```

Can someone help me with this method?

Comment: The requirement doesn't make any sense. I see, you want to get the angle between two sides, but none of them have `0.80693439407` as angle.

Comment: Also the first line gives cosine of angle, and to get an angle. you have to use `acos`

Answer (score 0):

[Wrong formula](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/trig-cosine-law.html).

```
// TODO: Special cases?  What if a or b are zero?
// Returned angle is in radians, not degrees.
public double getAngle(double a, double b, double c) { 
    return Math.acos((a*a + b*b - c*c)/(2.0*a*b));
}
```